# Nested_form, link_to_add ... three times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I have a problem with my nested_form, now when I click on my link_to_add button, three forms are displayed... It is the same for all my nested forms and this is new. I really don't know the reason, any idea ?

My code :

```
  <div id="new_upload">

    <%= f.fields_for :uploads do |file| %>

        <%= file.label :filename, 'Nom pièce jointe :'%>

        <%= file.text_field :name, :size => "19", :id=>"field" %>   

        <%= file.file_field :file if file.object.new_record? %> 

        <%= file.link_to_remove "Supprimer" %>

    <% end %>

  </div>

  <%= f.link_to_add "Ajouter pièce jointe", :uploads, :class=>"btn" %>
</div>
```

Comment: NO, just provide us with some code to help.

Comment: shouldn't it be 'form_for :uploads do'?

Comment: I think we need a little more information.  Can you show us the entire HTML page or form and point out what extra forms are being displayed that you don't want?  Also, posting the javascript or jQuery that you are using to dynamically add the fields could be useful too.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is linked with Rails 4 and Turbolinks. See https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form/issues/307 for instance.

You should be able to add `data-no-turbolinks` to your div to locally disable turbolinks.

Answer (score 0):

With me it was because the application.js was called in the body instead of head. Duh! See https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form/issues/286